# How can I make a union of temporary tables with JOIN statement?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, inner-join, temp-tables

Through "WITH" statement I have obtained three temporary tables:
"october_fall10",
"november_fall11" and
"december_fall12"
Now I want to perform an INNER JOIN (the Query below) with them through the variable "member_casual", but instead I receive the following alert
Error message: Table name "november_fall11" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.
Regardless that I wanted to do it with "december_fall12" the alert is repeated, but in reference to "december_fall12"

```
--This is Q1 from where I've got the 3 tables --

WITH october_fall10 AS
(SELECT 
   start_station_name,
   end_station_name,
   start_station_id,
   end_station_id,
   EXTRACT (DATE FROM started_at) AS start_date,
   EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM started_at) AS start_week_date,
   EXTRACT (TIME FROM started_at) AS start_time,    
   EXTRACT (DATE FROM ended_at) AS end_date,
   EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ended_at) AS end_week_date,    
   EXTRACT (TIME FROM ended_at) AS end_time,
   DATETIME_DIFF (ended_at,started_at, MINUTE) AS total_lenght,
   member_casual
FROM 
   `ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202010` AS fall_analysis
ORDER BY 
   started_at DESC)
SELECT
   member_casual,
   start_week_date,
   COUNT (member_casual) AS member_casual_start,
   TIME(
   EXTRACT(hour   FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
   EXTRACT(minute FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
   EXTRACT(second FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0'))
   ) AS avg_start_time
FROM 
   october_fall10
GROUP BY
   start_week_date,
   member_casual
ORDER BY 
   start_week_date DESC;  
WITH november_fall11 AS
(SELECT
   start_station_name,
   end_station_name,
   start_station_id,
   end_station_id,
   EXTRACT (DATE FROM started_at) AS start_date,
   EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM started_at) AS start_week_date,
   EXTRACT (TIME FROM started_at) AS start_time,    
   EXTRACT (DATE FROM ended_at) AS end_date,
   EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ended_at) AS end_week_date,    
   EXTRACT (TIME FROM ended_at) AS end_time,
   DATETIME_DIFF (ended_at,started_at, MINUTE) AS total_lenght,
   member_casual
FROM
   `ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202011` AS fall_analysis11 
ORDER BY 
   started_at DESC)
SELECT
   member_casual,
   start_week_date,
   COUNT (member_casual) AS member_casual_start,
   TIME(
   EXTRACT(hour   FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
   EXTRACT(minute FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
   EXTRACT(second FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0'))
   ) AS avg_start_time
FROM 
   november_fall11
GROUP BY
   start_week_date,
   member_casual
ORDER BY 
   start_week_date DESC;
WITH december_fall12 AS
(SELECT
   start_station_name,
   end_station_name,
   start_station_id,
   end_station_id,
   EXTRACT (DATE FROM started_at) AS start_date,
   EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM started_at) AS start_week_date,
   EXTRACT (TIME FROM started_at) AS start_time,    
   EXTRACT (DATE FROM ended_at) AS end_date,
   EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ended_at) AS end_week_date,    
   EXTRACT (TIME FROM ended_at) AS end_time,
   DATETIME_DIFF (ended_at,started_at, MINUTE) AS total_lenght,
   member_casual
FROM
   `ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202012` AS fall_analysis11 
ORDER BY 
   started_at DESC)
SELECT
   member_casual,
   start_week_date,
   COUNT (member_casual) AS member_casual_start,
   TIME(
   EXTRACT(hour   FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
   EXTRACT(minute FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
   EXTRACT(second FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0'))
   ) AS avg_start_time
FROM 
   december_fall12
GROUP BY
   start_week_date,
   member_casual
ORDER BY 
   start_week_date DESC; 

--This is Q2 from where I want to get the full combination--

SELECT
       october_fall10.member_casual,
       october_fall10.start_week_date,
       october_fall10.member_casual_start,
       october_fall10.avg_start_time,
       november_fall11.member_casual,
       november_fall11.start_week_date,
       november_fall11.member_casual_start,
       november_fall11.avg_start_time,
       december_fall12.member_casual,
       december_fall12.start_week_date,
       december_fall12.member_casual_start,
       december_fall12.avg_start_time
   FROM
       ( october_fall10 JOIN (november_fall11 JOIN december_fall12 USING (member_casual)) 
       USING 
       (member_casual) )
```

Comment: Please post all the detail, not just a query fragment, for a minimal test case which produces the behavior you don't understand.  It should be complete and executable, not full of non-executable images.  `CREATE TABLE ...; CREATE TABLE ...; INSERT ...; to provide test data;  WITH cte1 AS (...), cte2 AS (...), etc ... SELECT ... FROM cte1, etc...;`  Include the ultimate goal of all this, the exact expected result, given this test data, not just a description of your SQL.

Comment: Second, a `UNION` is entirely different than `JOIN`.  If you want to `UNION`, use a `UNION`.  If you want to `JOIN`, use a `JOIN`.  The title of your question suggests you're confused about your problem / goal.  Make sure you state the goal clearly, in terms you understand.  Don't use the terms 'UNION' or 'JOIN' if you don't really understand the purpose of those operations.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jon Armstrong, but if I really knew everything you are clarifying for me, I would never have uploaded my doubts to stackoverflow in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you create a 'table' using `WITH`, it's not a temporary table, it's a Common Table Expression (CTE).  It's useful to understand the different terminology, as they behave in different ways *(much like confusing petrol and diesel doesn't go so well)*.

One of the ways that they differ is that a CTE is no persisted in any way.  Once you make your final query, the CTE goes out of scope and can not be referenced again *(after the `;`, the CTE is 'gone')*.

This means that the pattern you want is...

```
WITH
  october_fall10 AS
(
  SELECT 
    start_station_name,
    end_station_name,
    start_station_id,
    end_station_id,
    EXTRACT (DATE FROM started_at) AS start_date,
    EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM started_at) AS start_week_date,
    EXTRACT (TIME FROM started_at) AS start_time,    
    EXTRACT (DATE FROM ended_at) AS end_date,
    EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ended_at) AS end_week_date,    
    EXTRACT (TIME FROM ended_at) AS end_time,
    DATETIME_DIFF (ended_at,started_at, MINUTE) AS total_lenght,
    member_casual
  FROM 
    `ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202010` AS fall_analysis
),
  october_fall10_aggregate AS
(
  SELECT
     member_casual,
     start_week_date,
     COUNT(member_casual) AS member_casual_start,
     TIME(
       EXTRACT(hour   FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
       EXTRACT(minute FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
       EXTRACT(second FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0'))
     )
       AS avg_start_time
  FROM 
     october_fall10
  GROUP BY
     start_week_date,
     member_casual
),
  november_fall11 AS
(
  <your query here>
),
  november_fall11_aggregate AS
(
  <your query here>
),
  december_fall12 AS
(
  <your query here>
),
  december_fall12_aggregate AS
(
  <your query here>
),
SELECT
  october_fall10_aggregate.member_casual,
  october_fall10_aggregate.start_week_date,
  october_fall10_aggregate.member_casual_start,
  october_fall10_aggregate.avg_start_time,
  november_fall11_aggregate.member_casual,
  november_fall11_aggregate.start_week_date,
  november_fall11_aggregate.member_casual_start,
  november_fall11_aggregate.avg_start_time,
  december_fall12_aggregate.member_casual,
  december_fall12_aggregate.start_week_date,
  december_fall12_aggregate.member_casual_start,
  december_fall12_aggregate.avg_start_time
FROM
  october_fall10_aggregate
JOIN
  november_fall11_aggregate
    USING (member_casual)
JOIN
  december_fall12_aggregate
    USING (member_casual)
```

This creates new CTEs with a `_aggregate` suffix, and then references those in your final query.

- Note that I also removed the `ORDER BY` from each CTE
- This is because CTEs (and table, temporary or otherwise) do ***not*** retain that ordering

Also, repeating all that code is insane.  You're much better off with all the data in a single table and writing the code once.  Failing that you can union the tables *'as-if'* they're one table...

```
WITH
  unioned AS
(
  SELECT 202010 AS source_tbl, * FROM `ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202010`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 202011 AS source_tbl, * FROM `ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202011`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 202012 AS source_tbl, * FROM `ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202012`
),
  extraction AS
(
  SELECT 
    source_tbl,
    member_casual,
    start_station_name,
    end_station_name,
    start_station_id,
    end_station_id,
    EXTRACT (DATE FROM started_at) AS start_date,
    EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM started_at) AS start_week_date,
    EXTRACT (TIME FROM started_at) AS start_time,    
    EXTRACT (DATE FROM ended_at) AS end_date,
    EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ended_at) AS end_week_date,    
    EXTRACT (TIME FROM ended_at) AS end_time,
    DATETIME_DIFF (ended_at,started_at, MINUTE) AS total_length
  FROM 
    unioned
)
SELECT
  member_casual,
  source_tbl,
  start_week_date,
  COUNT(member_casual) AS member_casual_start,
  TIME(
    EXTRACT(hour   FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
    EXTRACT(minute FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0')), 
    EXTRACT(second FROM AVG(start_time - '0:0:0'))
  )
    AS avg_start_time
FROM 
  extraction
GROUP BY
  member_casual,
  source_tbl,
  start_week_date
ORDER BY
  member_casual,
  source_tbl,
  start_week_date
```

This is ***NOT*** the same format as you had before, but is much more in keeping with the intended patterns for SQL.

Comment: @Rodrigo and the next step is to perform a kind of PIVOT, building on the last statement shown in this answer, to address the final part of your question, if that's still needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation @MatBailie! You have been very clear and didactic in your advice. Not only did you help me correct my problem but I have learned. Cheers.